# MLE Poisson vs Pareto

Tags: probability, statistics, optimization, maximum-likelihood

I am learning about the MLE. I got can do the proof of the Poisson distribution, which I learned from a video. The multiplication summation was a new thing for me, but I think I understand it. I can do the MLE of Poisson now correctly.

I'm still struggeling with the Pareto MLE. I also make use here of the multiplication summation and the rule ln(π) = Σ, because ln(a*b) = ln(a) + ln(b).

In the solution of the Pareto, there is a summation sign in the denominator, but it should be a muliplication summation. I don't see why.

Question:

- Why is there a multiplication summation in the Pareto MLE, but a summation in the Poisson?
- Why do I get a summation sign in my final answer of the pareto MLE, where it actually should me a multiplication summation?

Ter[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: $\sum \ln X_i=\ln (\prod X_i) \ne \ln \sum X_i$. Why are you comparing two different answers?

Comment: Maybe look at [Wikipedia > Pareto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Statistical_Inference) > Parameter estimation.

Comment: You can answer your question if your doubts are cleared.

Comment: Thanks @stubbornAtom for your reply! It I see what I did wrong. The when summating a logarithm you are actually muliplying the values within the logarithm, as you said in your reply. I wasn't fully aware of that before. The reason I was comparing two different answers was that I wanted to know why one proof was OK and the other not.